# How do I add the arrow image in the accordian below BEFORE the header and not as header's background?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, ajax

in the accordian below:-

Arrow-collaspsed image appears in the background of the header text when I want it BEFORE the header text. Also, when the Header of accordian is seleceted, the arrow-collapsed image is not changing to arrow- expanded..whats wrong??????

```
  <cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true" Visible="true" AutoSize="None" SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false" TransitionDuration="250" 
         HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader toggler" 
         HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeader toggler-expanded" 
         ContentCssClass="accordionContent"> 
            <HeaderTemplate> 

                <b style="color: Black">    
                    <%#Eval("Ques")%> 
                </b> 

            </HeaderTemplate>        

            <ContentTemplate> 
                <p> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuesAns")%></p>        
            </ContentTemplate> 
     </cc1:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some padding to your header to move the text away from the background image. I don't know the image dimensions you are using but try:

```
.accordionHeader {
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
padding-left:20px;
}
```

Of course you may want to remove the `margin-left` - I'm not sure whether this is there for the background-image or not..

When you expand the accordion - does the class name change in the html?

Comment: I fixed the image thing..thnx